# Change statusbar in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

What css selector should I use inside Stylish addon for chrome to change colors of the chrome's status bar (or status balloon) in the bottom?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to style chrome with stylish?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `div` with the `fbar` class.

```
.fbar{
    background: #BADA55;
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. Is there any documentation where  I can look up UI element classes? Or maybe some extension to be able to click on the UI and inspect element?

Comment: I think you can only style Pages with Stylish. Not the browser itself. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: well, I had successfully styled firefox UI with stylish, I believe the same should be with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```
.statuspanel-label 
{
   color: InfoText !important;
   border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3) !important;
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

Something along those lines ?